# In order to get my Gem published, do I absolutely need to write tests?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I would like to publish a Gem I wrote so it can be installed by users via `gem install my-gem`.  The *RubyGems* guide on how to [Make Your Own Gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#writing-tests) has a section on using `Test::Unit` and `rake` to test my code.

Writing tests is going to add significant development time to a Gem that (in this case) is somewhat trivial in nature.  I'd like to avoid it if possible.

**Is it necessary to write tests in order to publish a Gem or just a suggestion?**

Comment: There are no requirements other than a working gemspec, but there are some best practices. An aside: It is well worth learning and trying out a variation of test-driven development in future (personally I'd recommend learning rspec and BDD). If you integrate testing into the way you develop it is often *less* work overall, even for small projects. But there are some learning and practice/experience hurdles, and there is no need to put those in the way of publishing your gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a (good) suggestion, and is in no way required to publish a gem.